# How to run react-project in local from StackBlitz?

Tags: stackblitz

When I download from github project from StackBlitz, I got information:

```
m@m ~/c/g/m/a/react-tailwind-headless-ui-popover (main)> yarn start
yarn run v1.22.17
warning ../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /Users/m/code/github/mxcdh/app/react-tailwind-headless-ui-popover/public
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Bellow my github and running project in stackblitz:
https://github.com/mxcdh/react-tailwind-headless-ui-popover
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hpgtsa?file=README.md

What I should correct, that I can run this project on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install npm and parcel first, hopefully, the react stack on stackBlitz is compatible.

I had the same problem this morning, and I was able to fix it by tweaking these commands:

```
npm i -D parcel

npm run parcel -D
```

ps: I use Volta for the Node tool management: https://volta.sh/